# In DB2 LUW 9.5, is there any way to change the collating sequence without recreating the db?

Tags: collation, db2

The documentation says "no" :-)

I'm looking for some heady old DBA to whisper dark secrets about cludgy hacks that I'll get fired for sure for using ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't change the collating sequence without recreating the database.